# Как получить полный путь к файлу из File Input @angular/material

Tags: typescript, angular

Для выбора файла в Html шаблоне использую компонент FileInput @angular/material
app.component.html файл:

```
<div class="col-6">
    <mat-form-field>
      <ngx-mat-file-input [formControl]="fileControl"
                          placeholder="Выберите файл"
      >
        <mat-icon ngxMatFileInputIcon>folder</mat-icon>
      </ngx-mat-file-input>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

app.component.ts файл:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  fileControl: FormControl;
  public file;
  filename = '';
  constructor() {
    this.fileControl = new FormControl(this.file);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fileControl.valueChanges.subscribe((file: File) => {
      this.file = file;
      this.filename = file.name;
      console.log('fileName = ' + this.filename);
    })
  }
}
```

Все работает, вот только я получаю просто имя файла. А как мне определить полный путь к файлу, чтобы передать его на BackEnd для дальнейшей обработки?
Я не понимаю зачем может понадобиться просто имя файла, если я даже не знаю в какой папке он находится?

Comment: А зачем вам путь в файлу на компьютере? Обычно делают так:
- добавляют файл и он сразу загружается на сервер
- сервер при этом возвращает данные типа ссылки на файл, имя, mime тип и т.д.
- в поле формы кладется прямая ссылка на файл
- и затем идет запрос на создание сущности с этой ссылкой

В итоге в созданной сущности будет прямая ссылка на файл, который можно скачать или использовать для отображения (если картинка, например)